# Remove double quotes inside quotes of string

Tags: javascript

Remove double quotes inside double quotes of string using javascript.

I am receiving the string from the CSV file with double quotes inside double-quotes.

Actual input String is `"my testing is "Done"";` After reading CSV file, I am getting the below string,

```
var test = "my testing is ""Done""";
```

I would like to get the output: `my testing is "Done"` using javascript.

Expected Output:  `my testing is "Done"`

Actual output: `Main end Bus support location is \""A""`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace all the `""` with a single `"`

```js
var test = 'my testing is ""Done""',
    output = test.replace(/"+/g, '"');

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body onload="call()">
</body>
<script>
function call(){
    var ss = 'my testing is ""Done""';
    ss = ss.replace('""Done""',"\"Done\"");
}
</script>
</html>
```